# Google Maps Routes

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

I'm looking for some tutorial that helps me in making a Button that when I click the button I pass a location as a parameter and open Google Maps in the same location.

Example: `777th Street` when clicking the button will open Google Maps by tracing a route in my current location up to 777th Street. Is there any way?

Image example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please used below code like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Also below code is usedful when you know city:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=an+address+city"));
```

Also read below link it helps a lot to you:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

hope this helps.

Comment: hi, thanks!! I saw that it has a travelmod option, only currently it is only working for train and bike. How do I open it as a travelmode car?

I'm passing this link:
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Avenida+Afonso+Pena+%2C+Campo+Grande+%2C+MS+%2C+245&destination=Avenida+Afonso+Pena+%2C+Campo+Grande+%2C+MS+%2C+800&travelmode=transit

Comment: okay welcome and please mention this as solution worked answers for you. and closed this question.

Comment: Please see in document "travelmode" is there to used it.

Comment: travelmode (optional): Defines the method of travel. Options are driving, walking (which prefers pedestrian paths and sidewalks, where available), bicycling (which routes via bike paths and preferred streets where available), or transit. If no travelmode is specified, the Google Map shows one or more of the most relevant modes for the specified route and/or user preferences.

Comment: welcome @EmanuelBessa

Comment: Oh really cool ... Thank you you saved me !! hehe

Comment: Please closed it